# Azure DevOps Pipeline Rollback file for .NET MAUI install fails with '<' is an invalid start of a value

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, maui

Here is the error message.

Workload installation failed: '<' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.

Here is the Rollback file I created.

```
{
  "microsoft.net.sdk.ios": "17.2.8004/8.0.100",
  "microsoft.net.sdk.maui": "8.0.3/8.0.100"
}
```

Here is the script.

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Install Maui & iOS'
  inputs:
    script: 'dotnet workload install maui maui-ios --from-rollback-file https://www.mywebsite.com/Rollback/MauiJson --source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet8/nuget/v3/index.json --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'
```

I'm trying to create a Rollback file for .NET MAUI 8.0.3. This is for an iOS app.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That error generally means that something is trying to parse XML (most likely HTML) as JSON, which probably means authentication is failing and it's redirecting you to a login page or something similar.

Comment: @DanielMann It is being served up in a Blazor WASM page with no menu, layout etc... Perhaps that has something to do with it. In fact, it might be failing on the <pre> tag I'm using to display the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement, I managed to running the command referencing the local json file with source from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.

```
parameters:
  - name: MauiJson
    type: object
    default:
      microsoft.net.sdk.ios: 17.2.8004/8.0.100
      microsoft.net.sdk.maui: 8.0.3/8.0.100
variables:
  MauiJson:  ${{ convertToJson(parameters.MauiJson) }}

steps:
- script: |
    ls
    echo '$(MauiJson)' > MauiJson.json
    ls
  displayName: 'Create MauiJson.json'

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Install Maui & iOS'
  inputs:
    script: |
      cat MauiJson.json
      dotnet workload install maui maui-ios --from-rollback-file MauiJson.json --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

[image]

Hope this command could work for you as well. You may narrow down the cause of the issue caused by either your remote json contents or the package(s) in your Azure Artifacts source feed.

Comment: Awesome! How did you create or how do you handle the MauiJson.json file? Is there a Task for that or do you upload the file as an artifact? Thanks!

Comment: @Dumber_Texan2, Glad to help. I am afraid that I simply added the`MauiJson.json` file in my repo. While, I have updated my answer to generate the json file via script referencing the pipeline parameter that we can dynamically set at queue time.

Comment: Worked great! Thanks ever so much!